# VB.net A method to add a speciefied String to every line

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

Im while coding a Program that has a Mask with many Textfields and Comboboxes. Untill now everything is working fine, but I wannt to make it easier and add at the end of the line a word that will help me identify later the output of every line. Thats the streamWriter code

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Save As New SaveFileDialog()
    Dim myStreamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Save.Filter = "Text [*.txt*]|*.txt|All Files [*.*]|*.*"
    Save.CheckPathExists = True
    Save.Title = "Save File"
    Save.ShowDialog(Me)
    Try
        myStreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(Save.FileName)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox4.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ComboBox6.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ComboBox5.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox5.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox6.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox7.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox8.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox9.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox11.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox10.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox12.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox13.Text)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox14.Text)

        myStreamWriter.Flush()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

### And thats the Output txt file I get:

[Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfcrC.png)

[Wannt to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghpnU.png)

I know you can help me guys.

Comment: You need a delimiter, i wouldn't use spaces or commas, you could use the tab-character [`ControlChars.Tab`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars.tab(v=vs.100).aspx): `myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text & ControlChars.Tab & TextBox4.Text)`. Then you can parse it easily later.

Comment: Thx, I will try it and report

Comment: But is there no syntax or something like:
myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox13.Text)("This is the Serial Number")
??

Comment: Just append the strings: `myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox13.Text & "  " & "This is the Serial Number")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox13.Text & " " & "This is the Serial Number")